# How can I allow multiple sounds in pulseaudio?

Tags: fedora-15, pulse-audio

I am listening to online radio (flash) but if I start off another video clip locally or remotely, the video won't play until I either change the audio output of the clip to non-pulseaudio or close the online radio (stop won't work).

There are also no applications shown in Sound preference window.

This is not happening in Ubuntu, anyway to fix this? I am using Fedora 15 now.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to as if your flash plugin is actually *not* using Pulseaudio. One of the key benefits of Pulseaudio actually is that applications can share the audio more easily.

Try creating the following file as `.asoundrc` in your home directory (yes, with dot):

```
pcm.pulse { 
    type pulse
}
ctl.pulse {
     type pulse
}
pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}
ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}
```

Then restart your browser, to make sure flash picks up this change.